# Выходит ошибка при скачивании файла

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть программы такова, что она скачивает текстовый документ с сервера, перезаписывает его и снова отправляет на сервер. На моем компьютере она работает стабильно(Windows 8), на компьютере другого человека вылезает данная ошибка(Windows 7), а в месте, куда должен закачиваться данный файл, нет answers.txt(такое должно быть название и расширение), заместо него появляется файл с названием Task и неизвестным мне расширением(забыл записать).Интернет соединение имеется.Помогите решить данную проблему, буду очень благодарен

метод скачивания файла:

```
 private string[] DownloadFileFromServer(string from, string to) 
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(from, to);
            }
            string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(to);
            File.Delete(to);
            return file;
        }
        catch (Exception a) { return null; }
    }
```

Метод отправки файла:

```
 private void UploadFileToServer(string from, string to) // отправка файла 
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            Uri ftp = new Uri("" + to);
            client.UploadFile(ftp.ToString(), from);
            File.Delete(from);            
        }
    }
```

Метод print();

```
 public void print(int number_question) // вопросы 
    {
        switch (number_question)
        {
            case 1:question_box.Text = "<text>_1";
                break;
            case 2:question_box.Text = "<text>_2";
                break;
            case 3:question_box.Text = "<text>_3";
                break;
            case 4:question_box.Text = "<text>_4";
                break;               
            default:
                timerTask.Enabled = false;
                panel1.Visible = true;
                List<string> fail = File.ReadAllLines("backup/Backup.txt").ToList<string>();
                fail.Add(date.Day + "." + date.Month + "." + date.Year + " " + date.Hour + ":" + date.Minute);
                fail.Add(fname + " " + name + " " + class_);
                fail.Add("Времени ушло: " + time);
                for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
                {
                    fail.Add(i + 1 + " " + answer[i]);
                }
                fail.Add(new string('-', 30));
                File.WriteAllLines("backup/Backup.txt", fail);

                List <string> file = DownloadFileFromServer("http://fschat.ucoz.net/Results.txt", "Task").ToList<string>();
                file.Add(date.Day + "." + date.Month + "." + date.Year + " " + date.Hour + ":" + date.Minute);
                file.Add("Времени ушло: " + time);
                file.Add(fname + " " + name+" "+class_);
                for(int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++)
                {
                    file.Add(i + 1 + ": " + answer[i]);
                }
                file.Add(Environment.NewLine);
                File.WriteAllLines("Results.txt", file);
                UploadFileToServer("Results.txt", "fschat.ucoz.net/Results.txt");
                MessageBox.Show("Тестирование окончено!");
                Application.Exit();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Метод print() вызывается здесь

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) // вход 
    {           
        timerTask.Interval = 1000;
        timerTask.Tick += delegate (object sender_, EventArgs a) { time += 1; };
        timerTask.Enabled = true;

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fname_box.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name_box.Text)||String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(class_box.Text))
            MessageBox.Show("Не все поля заполнены!");
        else
        {
            panel_test.Visible = true;
            fname = fname_box.Text;
            name = name_box.Text;
            class_ = class_box.Text;
            print(question);              
        }                              
    }
```

Comment: И где код, по звездам вам помогать? Или по фазам луны? Использовать телепатию?

Comment: И для начала, обновите .Net на машине другого человека. В первую очередь.

Comment: Полный код ошибки бы еще. Вообще судя по всему ошибка не в скачивании. Не хватает данных. Смотрите код ошибки, и найдите это место в коде. попытайтесь понять, чего у вас там гвоздями прибито к вашей машине.

Comment: @Сергей Компьютер учительский, я не могу знать, что там прибито может быть, дай бог, что ещё работает

Comment: В таком случае вам тут мало чем помогут.

Comment: Смотрите. У вас на фото изображен `StackTrace`, откуда исключение было вызвано. Нужно его полностью скопировать, чтобы понять, что упало. И второе. Вы проверяете, что метод `DownloadFileFromServer` вернул не `null`

Comment: Ошибка может быть связана с тем, что доступ к данному ресурсу закрыт.

Comment: @Trymount Программа то у меня работает и у других людей, но на этом компьютере почему-то нет.Доступ к ресурсу есть

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH  Давайте начнем с простого. Вы сами запускали это программу на компьютере, на котором она не работает?

Comment: @Trymount сам писал, сам запускал, сам проверял, другим людям скидывал, у всех работало. Вот сегодня запустил на компьютере, на котором не работает, вышла такая ошибка

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH интересует только неработающий компьютер. Попробуйте на нём скачать этот файл через браузер. И приведите пожалуйста код метода print и место, в котором он вызывается. Ошибка, по видимому, в нём.

Comment: @Trymount Методы предоставил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49222/discussion-between-trymount-and-zoom-smash).

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines("backup/Backup.txt")` - путь задан относительно; проблема может быть в этом. Также может не быть прав на доступ к указанному пути (обрабатывайте исключения).

Comment: Проверьте куда скинут файл. Запустите с правами админа, добавьте в исключения к антивирусу. Так-же следует добавить проверки на null во всех местах, где файл скачивается с интернета. И обязательно следует добавить try-catch блок на запись-чтение в файл-из файла! Тогда все станет ясно, как белый день.

Comment: В методе скачки файла! Обратите внимание на ваш кэч  catch (Exception a) { return null; } вот он ваш гневный нулл, Вставьте туда заглушку MessageBox.Show(a.Message); Можно даже File.Delete(to); дополнительным catch обернуть. Но проблема 100% в этом методе. Сделаете мессаге бокс и все понятно будет.

Comment: @xSx уже выяснили, что там 407 ошибка, проблема с прокси

Comment: прокси Оо. Да.. с запросами все приходится учитывать, просто автор говорил, что с браузера доступ был, получается в нем настроено все нормально было?

Comment: @xSx дело в том, что в школе не рабоатет, там прокси есть, а так программа и всё остальное рабочее